# r doesn't see data frame as characters; can't grep; wrong use of as.character()?

Tags: r, dataframe, class

EDIT, A DAY LATER: The answers to this question have shown me that I needed to edit my code quite substantially. So basically the question has now gone away because I'm not `grep`ping in a data-frame any more. The code is now as follows, much cleaner.

I'm leaving the original question here in case my learning process helps anyone, though.

```
# 1. Find lines containing both "un" and "ɛ̃"
original_lines <- readLines('Test.txt')
lines_with_pattern <- grep('un.*ɛ̃', original_lines, value = TRUE)

# CHANGE PHONES TO FIND AND PHONES TO ADD

# 2. Duplicate the line in which the pattern occurs and change the relevant phoneme
modified_lines <- character()
for (line in lines_with_pattern)
  modified_lines <- c(modified_lines, gsub("ɛ̃", "œ̃", line))

# 3. Combine modified lines with original lines
all_lines <- c(original_lines, modified_lines)

# 4. Sort the lines alphabetically
sorted_lines <- sort(all_lines)

# 5. Print the sorted lines
writeLines(sorted_lines, 'myfile.txt', sep = '\\n')
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION

I am trying to grep a data frame consisting of rows of two columns with tab separation between the columns, e.g.

```
              V1            V2
17 nempruntèrent ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t ɛ ʁ
18     vemprunté   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
19    fempruntée   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
20   wempruntées   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
21    2empruntés   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
```

(excerpt--the last five rows of the data frame. The first col contains dummy French-like words; the second col contains International Phonetic Alphabet transcriptions.)

```
test <- read.delim('Test.txt', header=FALSE)
print(test)
```

produces a printout as above, so it looks as if R 'knows' what's in the data frame.

But then I want to `grep` for certain strings, so I've tried

```
# 1. Find lines containing both "un" and "ɛ̃"
lines_with_pattern <- grep("un", test, value = TRUE)
print(lines_with_pattern)
```

and this doesn't work.

The above `grep` results in `named character(0)`. This means R is not finding the characters it's looking for, so I've tried

```
test <- read.delim('Test.txt', header=FALSE)
test <- as.character(test)
```

I don't think I'm using as.character() right, as that snippet produces e.g.

```
     V1 V2
 
[17,] NA NA
[18,] NA NA
[19,] NA NA
[20,] NA NA
[21,] NA NA
```

(again the last five rows of the output)

and therefore `print(test)` produces

```
[1] "c(17, 18, 12, 20, 1)"
[2] "c(8, 6, 6, 6, 6)"
```

(last five figures in the resulting vectors)

and

```
lines_with_pattern <- grep("un", test, value = TRUE)
# value = TRUE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = TRUE, invert = FALSE)
print(lines_with_pattern)
```

produces `character(0)`.

So: I don't understand the vectors that `print(test)` produces in the example just above--the numbers don't seem to refer to anything corresponding to the data. And, my original question: what do I need to do to be able to `grep` this data-set?

Sorry for the very long message, and for the noob question, but thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Please add `dput(head(test, 10))` to your post because it's hard to see the data's structure from a mere `print`.

Comment: You can't really use `grep` on an entire data frame at once. You need to give it individual vectors to work with. If you only want to know which items in the first column contain `"un"`, then try `grep('un', as.character(test$V1))`.

Answer (score 3):

`grep()` cannot be used as-is on data frames. Moreover, data frame's do not work well for row-wise operations which is what you seem to be interested in doing. In base R, I would use a combination of `apply()` (which will do an implicit conversion of your data to a character matrix) and `grepl()`:

```r
which(apply(
  test,
  MARGIN = 1,
  FUN = function(x) any(grepl("un", x)) & any(grepl("ɛ̃", x))
))
```

This will give you all the rows where both "un" and "ɛ̃" appear. The use of `which()` is to get row numbers rather than a logical vector (which also works perfectly fine for subsetting on its own).

Comment: Thanks @rps1227! This gave me the hint that I was using a `grep` sledgehammer to crack a little nut, and not even using the sledgehammer properly either. As a result though I have another question...

Comment: @hall_damien Then go ahead and edit your question to add the new aspects that you have now become aware of.

Comment: I've done that. Thanks.